# Is there anyway to resend `ObjectCreated` notifications for certain files in `S3`?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

I have a processing pipeline that triggers on `ObjectCreated` notifications for one of my buckets in `S3` (which are sent to an `SQS` queue). I'd like to be able to artificially recreate those notifications, in particular to send older files through the pipeline (or to just run everything through the pipeline again because of a change in my processing). Is there a built in functionality that does this ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe issuing an `aws s3 cp` command with the same value for both source and destination will cause another `ObjectCreated` event to be fired.

Comment: Yes I've thought of that, but it's somewhat of a "dirty" solution in that it changes the file metadata, and risks file loss in case the `cp` goes awry. For now I'm going to try to write the `SQS` myself.